# How to transform: cut(Orange.class) -> cut(Orange)

Tags: java

How to transform:  cut(Orange.class)  -> cut(Orange)

cut function look like below:

```
protected <T extends Fruit> T cut(Class<T> fruitClass){
    try {
        return fruitClass.newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get the type from the passed instance:

```
protected <T extends Fruit> T cut(T fruit) {
    try {
        return (T)fruit.getClass().newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException e) {
        // throw some exception or return an alternative instance or null
    }
}
```

Comment: The passed in parameter is a ClassType not Instance.

`public class Orange extends Fruit`

Comment: @JaxT I thought you wanted to change the argument from `Class<T>` to `T`. Isn't that what the question was about? If that's not what you meant, what did you mean by `cut(Orange.class) -> cut(Orange)`?

Comment: In short: Is there anyway that i can remove '.class' from Orange.class.

Because i found that cut(Orange.class) is ugly. Elegant look is cut(Orange)

And Orange is a class not an instance.

Comment: @JaxT If you wish to pass a `Class<Orange>` to your method, you can either write `Orange.class` (there's nothing ugly about it) or `orange.getClass()`, where `orange` is an instance of `Orange`.

Comment: thanks for clarification on that @Eran - So there is no way to achieve what i am looking for - will mark this answer correct because it describe correctly what to do when you pass in an Instance

Answer (score 0):

Using `.class` for class identification is very easy and removing it could be problematic.
But you can use [Class.forName(String className)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) function.

Example:

```
     protected <T extends Fruit> T cut(String fruitClass) {
    try {
        return Class.forName(fruitClass).newInstance();
    } catch (InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | ClassNotFoundException  e) {
        // throw some exception or return an alternative instance or null
    }
   }
```

Usage of this function would look like `cut("com.example.fruit.Orange")`. But remember you need to pass **whole name** of that class.

Comment: Just quick comment. Using `Orange.class` is much prettier than `com.example.fruit.Orange`

Comment: yes Orange.class is prettier than "com.example.fruit.Orange"